# how to get a DisplayLink display adapter working in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: usb, display, xrandr, displaylink

I have a [UGA-2K-A USB 2.0 to DVI DisplayLink graphics adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0038P1TP4) and I'm trying to get it to work on Ubuntu 13.10 in order to hook it up to a display.

First, I confirmed that the package `xserver-xorg-video-modesetting` was installed. It was by default.

Next, I connected the graphics adapter. The `dmesg` output on initial connection connection was as follows:

```
[ 4679.672775] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 4679.690786] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[ 4679.810714] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[ 4680.025025] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 4680.045611] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=0378
[ 4680.045621] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4680.045626] usb 2-2: Product: Plugable UGA-2K-A
[ 4680.045631] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
[ 4680.045634] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 786492
[ 4680.097418] [drm] vendor descriptor length:22 data:22 5f 01 00 20 05 00 01 03 00 04
[ 4680.330439] udl 2-2:1.0: fb1: udldrmfb frame buffer device
[ 4680.330452] [drm] Initialized udl 0.0.1 20120220 on minor 1
[ 4680.330503] usbcore: registered new interface driver udl
```

I understand that the line

```
udl 2-2:1.0: fb1: udldrmfb frame buffer device
```

implies that the kernel driver has bound.

At this point, the LED on the device was not lit and the display connected to the graphics adapter did not register a signal.

Some information on the kernel and xrandr is the following:

```
uname -r
3.11.0-18-generic

xrandr --version
xrandr program version       1.4.0
Server reports RandR version 1.4

xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x49 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

I rebooted the computer with the graphics adapter attached. The relevant `dmesg` output on boot was as follows:

```
[    2.118884] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.138973] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=0378
[    2.138978] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.138980] usb 2-2: Product: Plugable UGA-2K-A
[    2.138982] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
[    2.138984] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 786492
[    2.144629] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    2.149981] [drm] vendor descriptor length:22 data:22 5f 01 00 20 05 00 01 03 00 04
[    2.262948] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2394.457 MHz
[    2.290353] open /dev/fb0 user=0 fb_info=ffff88020e9e2800 count=1
[    2.293046] [drm] write mode info 153
[    2.293051] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 210x65
[    2.307012] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.317593] udl 2-2:1.0: fb0: udldrmfb frame buffer device
[    2.317595] udl 2-2:1.0: registered panic notifier
[    2.317599] [drm] Initialized udl 0.0.1 20120220 on minor 0
[    2.317628] usbcore: registered new interface driver udl
[    2.324247] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc
[    2.324251] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.491175] usb 2-5: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
```

At this point, the LED on the device is lit and the display connected to the graphics adapter registers a signal (though the image is black).

The output of `xrandr --listproviders` remains the following:

```
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x49 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

I am not sure what to do next. According to [a forum post](http://www.displaylink.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-62411.html), it may be that I need to slave the second graphics device to the first, but I have no idea how to do this. I would really appreciate some guidance. :) Thanks!

Comment: Did upgrade solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the framerate is a little sluggish at times and there can be misidentifications of the the display dimensions occasionally, it is working in Ubuntu 14.04, so upgrading is one solution.

Comment: I would like to add that the USB3.0 Displaylink devices are NOT supported under Linux, only the USB2 devices. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/517339/displaylink-usb-3-0-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04lts